# What's best approach for importing Multiple-Language Packs(i18n) in javascript(React)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, internationalization, devextreme

I'm currently working on a project that requires support for multiple languages.
I have language packs stored as JSON files, and I'm trying to determine the best approach for importing these language packs into my program.

Specifically, I'm concerned about the performance impact when dealing with a large number of language packs.

1. use the `import` statement to import the language packs individually whenever they are needed.

However, I'm worried that this approach might result in importing all the language packs each time, which could consume excessive resources and affect performance.

2. use the `require` function to load the language packs dynamically when needed.

This approach seems more flexible, as it allows me to import specific language packs as required, potentially reducing the resource consumption.

I would like to know the advantages and disadvantages of each approach in terms of resource usage and performance.

Here is my current implementation approach. When the user selects a language, the following code snippet is executed.

```js
let language = this.language || 'en';
if (this.languages.find((l) => l.code == language) == null) {
  language = 'en';
}
const messages = await import(
  `devextreme/localization/messages/${language}.json`
);
const externalMessages = await import(`./../i18n/${language}.json`);

const mergedMessages = {
  [language]: {
    ...messages[language],
    ...externalMessages[language],
  },
};
console.log(mergedMessages);
loadMessages(mergedMessages);
locale(language);
```

Additionally, if there are any alternative methods or best practices for handling multiple language packs efficiently, I would appreciate any insights or recommendations.

Thank you!

Comment: I think the way of using multiple languages is enough. Importing a necessary language file when you need it is a great approach. Because you thought the performance of your system and if it is necessary, you import. when i saw your question, i investigated different approaches related to your question but i did not find any suitable approach.

Comment: @Halil Thanks. In fact, I was a newcomer to full-stack engineering, I initially thought there would be a standard approach, similar to established disciplines.